How can I sequentially power USB devices?
In a project, around 4 remote sensors (Vallon VMH4 metal detectors) must get powered up to a Linux SBC, and since their placement on the rover is important, we must exactly know which sensor in which particular location has powered up.
This devices provide a USB cable and send NMEA sentence through a COM/TTY port. The USB is provided from a microcontroller so it's not a FTDI or something similar. Also, the devices can be swapped with other models without my intervention so I can't keep track of serial numbers or types.
The solution that I thought of, is to power them up sequentially while the SBC tracks which COM/TTY pops up, and marks it as the sensor in that specific location. I found many ICs to switch 5V power, but since for USB we need to power the device first, then connect D+/D- (as in USB A staggered pads) I don't know how to do that. Is there any solution to this problem?

Can you dedicate a specific USB port for a specific location? (I presume yes, as you're contemplating identifying them by sequencing the power)... if yes, then you can just inspect the USB tree and determine which device is on which port - no need to control power!

this is an XY question ... you think that sequential powering is a solution to a problem, so you ask about sequential powering ... it may not be the only solution... please ask about the problem instead

But you don't need to do anything with D+ and D-.
So you don't have problem that requires a solution.
Simply use a load switch on the 5V VBUS line.
The devices can't signal to host that they are ready to communicate until they have 5V supply turned on.
This applies to both bus-powered devices (e.g. a mouse that gets power from host) and self-powered devices (e.g. a printer with mains inlet for power).
Any device that signals to host that they are ready to communicate before they have 5V VBUS from host are thus non-compliant devices and should not exist.

Unfortunately devices that are non-compliant are basically "all" devices. Every device has to be tested on a case by case basis to make sure that it behaves the way it should. They are the bane of my existence

@vini_i Now that is not true. For example a mouse cannot signal it's ready for communication if it gets no power from computer and has no other supply.

You say that but I have seen a mouse that could power itself via the data lines. I got one of those USB hubs with the buttons to kill individual ports. This stupid mouse, it needed the power to enumerate, but after that, turning power off to the mouse did not kill it.

@vini_i That sounds impossible as the data lines from host must float at 0V if nothing is connected. I guess it may have non-compliant amount of capacitance or has very low power consumption and once received power and enumerated, it can clamp parasitic power from data pins if VBUS off. I do wonder, is it a cheap no-name mouse?

Yes, cheap no name mouse.

@vini_i That's a part of the problem. If it is too cheap to have official USB logos etc, you cannot assume it being USB compliant.

@Justme The staggered pinout on USB A made me think that devices must be powered on, BEFORE data lines are connected, so I though I can't power them on or off while the data lines are always connected. The devices are self-powered BTW. Right now based on the answers it seems I thought wrong about the whole idea.

You're trying to solve a problem that you don't have: Your Hub (including the root hub) numbers its USB ports, so through the bus numbering, it's possible to identify USB devices, no matter in which order they were powered up.
Don't invent a complex hardware solution to something a few lines of software could do! In the case of Linux that's especially easy, with udev rules you can set "stable" device names based on bus path.

Linux yoiu say?
/dev/serial/by-path/
Will identify the devices according to how they are physically connected (which port of which hub etc)
